# Code for making a triangle not working

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a code for school where it makes a hollow triangle with a symbol input and a maximum number of symbol input. Instead of creating a triangle, it is instead making a vertical line of the symbols, so with an input of A and 9, instead of this:

```
    A
   A A
  A   A
 A     A
AAAAAAAAA
```

It Gives me a long line of A's

Here is my code

```
def SetValues():
    global symbol
    symbol = input("Enter Symbol: ")
    InputMaxNumberOfSymbols()
    global NumberOfSpaces
    NumberOfSpaces = (MaxNumberOfSymbols - 1) / 2
    global NumberOfSymbols
    NumberOfSymbols = 1


def InputMaxNumberOfSymbols():
    global MaxNumberOfSymbols
    MaxNumberOfSymbols = int(input("Max Number of symbols: "))
    while MaxNumberOfSymbols % 2 == 0:
        MaxNumberOfSymbols = int(input("Max Number of symbols: "))

def OutputSpaces():
    for i in range(0, int(NumberOfSpaces)):
        print(" ")


def OutputSymbols():
    for i in range(0, NumberOfSymbols):
        print(symbol)
        print("\n")


def AdjustValuesForNextRow():
    global NumberOfSpaces
    NumberOfSpaces -= 1
    global NumberOfSymbols
    NumberOfSymbols += 2


#Main Code
SetValues()
while not NumberOfSymbols > MaxNumberOfSymbols:
    OutputSpaces()
    OutputSymbols()
    AdjustValuesForNextRow()
```

Comment: I hate to be rude but this coding style is pretty weird. Take a look at [this](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful) for why you might want to avoid all those globals and [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a style guide that many people follow when writing python code.

Comment: You'll need another variable that'll keep track of the number of spaces that needs to go between the symbols in one line.

Comment: Try printing out the values of your variables at various stages of your program (e.g. at the beginning/end of your main loop).  Or even better, learn to use a debugger and step through your code so you can see where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited since a commenter mentioned it was for python 3

one of the issues that you are facing is that print statements automatically move to the next line. Change print statements from

```
print(something)
```

to

```
print(something, end = "")
```

note the use of the comma after the print